# (notation question) what does $k//2$ means as in $\tilde{x}=\sum(-1)^{k // 2} x_{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, solution-verification, proof-explanation, parity

I found a notation this notation in this result:

> (The reverse involution) If $x=\sum x_{k}\left(x_{k} \in \wedge^{k}
> E \right)$ is a multivector, we define $\tilde{x}=\sum(-1)^{k // 2}
> x_{k}(k / / 2=\lfloor q / 2\rfloor) .$ The linear map $\wedge E
> \rightarrow \wedge E, x \mapsto \tilde{x},$ is an involution that is
> called the reverse involution of $\wedge E$. Since it satisfies
> $\widehat{x \wedge y}=\tilde{y} \wedge \tilde{x}$ for all $x, y \in
> \wedge E,$ we say that it is an algebra antiautomorphism of $\wedge E.$
>
> Proof The key point is that if $x=x_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{k}$ is
> a $k$ -blade, then $\tilde{x}=x_{k} \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{1}$.
> Indeed, since the exterior product is skew-symmetric, $x_{k}
> \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{1}=(-1)^{\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ 2\end{array}\right)} x$ and
> $(-1)^{\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ 2\end{array}\right)}=(-1)^{k // 2}$
> because $\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ has the same
> parity as $k / / 2$. With this, the proof is easily completed.

By googling the notation I found pragramming explanations of the same notation and not one in the context of algebra.

From what's written on the proof $(k / / 2=\lfloor q / 2\rfloor) $ what I guessed didn't make sense, I also thought there was a mistake because $k$ is a natural number, $q$ was noted as a metric or a bilinear form all along, I don't see why it would be the case, but if k//2 meant the floor of $k/2$ instead of $q/2$ then $\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ would be of the same parity as the floor of the result of the division of $k$ by 2, I tried a few examples, it sounds to be the case , if so, how ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. The programming interpretation of `k//2` is the floor (or integer part) of $k/2$, so no ambiguity when $k\ge 0$.  You didn't use the limits of summation, but I assume you have $k=1,\ldots,n$ in mind.

Comment: You can check the parity by looking at the cases of $k$ modulo $4$.